# PancakeView Gradient with only 2 colors

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to use `PancakeView` with only 2 colors for gradient background. Looks like it requires 3 colors. Is there any option or sample syntax?

```
<LinearGradientBrush x:Name="Theme" EndPoint="0,1">
            <GradientStop Color="#48b6a6" Offset="0.1" />
            <GradientStop Color="#2b78d4" Offset="1.0" />
</LinearGradientBrush>
```

Comment: I believe it can takes as much colors as you want. In [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64742108/5228202) just remove one of the `<pancake:GradientStop .../>`. Are you getting an error ?

Comment: @Cfun Hello, Yes I remember your answer it was helpful to understand the concept of it but I have and lineargradient background colors so I keep them consistent. Is there a way to put these code into pancake syntax.  My code looks like this:            <LinearGradientBrush x:Name="Theme" EndPoint="0,1">
                <GradientStop Color="#48b6a6" Offset="0.1" />
                <GradientStop Color="#2b78d4" Offset="1.0" />
            </LinearGradientBrush>

Comment: just replace `<GradientStop ...` by `<pancake:GradientStop ...`

Comment: What are you using `x:Name="Theme"` for ?

Comment: It was just maybe use it button colors for again using it.

Comment: I don't know if you can define it with a unique key as a style and then consume it as a ressource with `StaticRessource` that would be interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put it in `PancakeView` syntax from

```
<LinearGradientBrush x:Name="Theme" EndPoint="0,1">
    <GradientStop Color="#48b6a6" Offset="0.1"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#2b78d4" Offset="1.0"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>
```

To

```
<pancake:PancakeView BackgroundGradientEndPoint="0,1" ...>
        <pancake:PancakeView.BackgroundGradientStops>
            <pancake:GradientStopCollection>
                <pancake:GradientStop Color="#48b6a6" Offset="0.1"/>
                <pancake:GradientStop Color="#2b78d4" Offset="1"/>
            </pancake:GradientStopCollection>
        </pancake:PancakeView.BackgroundGradientStops>
...
</pancake:PancakeView>
```